# Why is lodash _.includes not finding that my Array contains the Object it's checking?

Tags: javascript, lodash

https://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/yLv6t5am/

LoDash [_.includes](https://lodash.com/docs#includes)

```
var searchedTickers = [
    {
        ticker: 'GOOG'
    }
]

var ticker = { ticker: 'GOOG' }

var found = _.includes(searchedTickers, ticker);

console.log(found);
```

^ It's currently telling me that `found = false`. It should be `true`.

Comment: _.includes won't work on object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lodash doesnt compare the object's attributes' values; it compares if they are the same object (internal references).

This code will print `true`, because it's the same object:

```
var ticker = { ticker: 'GOOG' }

var searchedTickers = [ticker]

var found = _.includes(searchedTickers, ticker);

console.log(found);
```

Comment: Ah ok thanks! I also ended up using this, which works `var notFound = _.isEmpty(_.find(array, item));`